# How create slider carousel 3 item center

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, carousel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tcv5.png)

I tried owl carousel 2 and slick js with center mode but it only one item center

owl carousel 2:

```
$('.journals-slider').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        smartSpeed: 500,
        center: true,
        nav: true,
        navText: ['<div class="btn-nav"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>', '<div class="btn-nav"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>'],
        dots: false,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 2
            },
            768: {
                items: 4
            },
            992: {
                items: 6
            }
        }
    });
```

slick js:

```
$('.journals-slider').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '60px',
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Can u help me create slider as image?
Is there any js that can do the same function that can refer me to the reference?